# how to increase return size of yahoo related Suggestions php

Tags: php, api, yahoo

I have this code that will return keyword suggestion from yahoo using the api.

```
function suggestion($keyword,$keyid){
        $search_key= str_replace(' ','+',$keyword);
        $app ="D4FRJzjeHUCoJsYIeYV4E6XFUlJpX.o1TWALuI-";
        $search = "http://search.yahooapis.com/WebSearchService/V1/relatedSuggestion?appid=".$app."&query=".$search_key."&output=json";
        $content= file_get_contents($search);
        $json = json_decode($content); 
        foreach($json->ResultSet->Result as $string){
            //insert to database
                 echo $string."<br />";
        }
    }
```

but it only return 4 keyword suggestion.
I tried adding &results=30 in the search, but no luck it still return 4 keyword suggestion only.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: This sounds like something to look for in the yahoo API documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the docs, http://developer.yahoo.com/search/web/V1/relatedSuggestion.html

its being shut down in a month, why bother using it now.